# How to resolve Error 7375 in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, historian, proficy

I m using Sql Server 2005 to develop report. for that I have created linked server to proficy historian in sql server 2005. I have a following stored procedure.

```
declare @batch varchar(50)
set @batch='LT20623'
drop table #batchdata
create table #batchdata
(
    [value] varchar(20),
    [timestamp] datetime
)
drop table #batchdata2
create table #batchdata2
(
    tagname varchar(50),
    [timestamp] varchar(50),
    [value] varchar(30)
)

insert into #batchdata select * from Batch_1 order by timestamp desc

declare @query varchar(500)
declare @starttime datetime
declare @endtime datetime
declare @subsequenttag varchar(50)
set @starttime=(select min(timestamp) from #batchdata where value=@batch)

declare @subsequentcount int
set @subsequentcount=(select count(*) from #batchdata where timestamp>@starttime)

if (@subsequentcount =0)
begin
    select @endtime=getdate()
end
else
begin
    select @endtime=min(timestamp) from #batchdata where value!=@batch and timestamp>@starttime
end
select @starttime as starttime, @endtime as endtime
declare @stime varchar(20)
declare @etime varchar(20)
set @stime=convert(varchar,datepart(month,@starttime))+'/'+convert(varchar,datepart(day,@starttime))+'/'+convert(varchar,datepart(year,@starttime))+' '+convert(varchar,datepart(hour,@starttime))+':'+convert(varchar,datepart(minute,@starttime))+':'+convert(varchar,datepart(second,@starttime))
set @etime = convert(varchar,datepart(month,@endtime))+'/'+convert(varchar,datepart(day,@endtime))+'/'+convert(varchar,datepart(year,@endtime))+' '+convert(varchar,datepart(hour,@endtime))+':'+convert(varchar,datepart(minute,@endtime))+':'+convert(varchar,datepart(second,@endtime))
set @query='select * from openquery(PIMS_HIST,''set fmtonly OFF starttime="'+@stime+'",endtime="'+@etime+'",samplingmode=rawbytime,rowcount=0 select tagname,timestamp,value from ihrawdata where tagname=PIMS-LOTE-1.LOTE.PIMS.Global.AIPV_28'')'
insert into #batchdata2 exec(@query)

select  * from #batchdata2
```

when I execute the above created procedure it throws an error 7357. Please help me.

Comment: [Error 7357](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226406(v=sql.80).aspx): Either the specified table or columns do not exist or the login used to connect to the provider does not have the required permissions on the table or columns. Have you ensured that the table names and login are correct?

Comment: What line does the error occur on?